# How can I ignore a blank line in a srt file using Java

Tags: java, file, blank-line

I have a srt file like below and I want to remove blank line : in line no 3

```
**
1
Line1: 00:00:55,888 --> 00:00:57,875.  
Line2:Antarctica  
Line3:   
Line4:2  
Line5:00:00:58,375 --> 00:01:01,512  
Line6:An inhospitable wasteland.    
**
```

```
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("line.srt");
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("m/line.srt");
        int i = 0;
        while(((i =fin.read()) != -1)){
            if(i != 0)
            fout.write((byte)i);
        }
```

Comment: Is the text `Line3` a part of the text in the file?

Comment: Basically you want to split each incoming line - into a part that contains "Line:number" and a part that holds all the rest. If the rest is empty, you know that you can ignore that line. You could be using regular expressions; or do a simple `indexOf()` to find the position of the first ":" in your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. Steps:

1) `FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("line.srt");` this is to get the file to a bufferedreader in the next step

2) `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));` get the text file to a buffereader

3) `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("newline.srt");` use a print writer to write the string of every line in the new text file

4) `String line = reader.readLine();` read next line

5) `while(line != null){
    if (!line.trim().equals("")) {` check that line is not null and that line is not empty

6) `out.println(line);` write line (not empty) to the output .srt file

7) `line = reader.readLine();` get new line

8) `out.close();` close PrintWriter in the end...

```
import java.io.*;
class RemoveBlankLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("line.srt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("newline.srt");
        int i = 0;
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null){
                    if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
                        out.println(line);
                    }
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }    
            out.close();
    }
}
```

INPUT:

```
**
1
00:00:55,888 --> 00:00:57,875.  
Antarctica  

2  
00:00:58,375 --> 00:01:01,512  
An inhospitable wasteland.    
**
```

OUTPUT:

```
**
1
00:00:55,888 --> 00:00:57,875.  
Antarctica  
2  
00:00:58,375 --> 00:01:01,512  
An inhospitable wasteland.    
**
```

By the way, make sure you are clear when you ask your questions, because the way you state your problem I assumed Line1, Line2, etc are part of your input file, and I have prepared another solution which I had to change... Make sure you are clear and precise so that you get the proper answers !

Comment: Line: is not a part of the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
BufferedReader br = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("line.srt"));
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("m/line.srt"));

    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if(line.trim().length() == 0) {
            continue;
        } else {
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }

    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    br.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hope this help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  Path myPath = Paths.get("e:\\", "1.txt");
  List<String> ls ;
  ls = Files.readAllLines(myPath, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("e:\\2.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
        String []temp = ls.get(i).split(":");
        if(temp.length>1) {
           out.println(ls.get(i));
        }
    }
    out.close();
}
```